# replace comma in specific column value

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which contains 6 columns, each field separated by "I" the second last column contains amount field.

```
140121059|01/01/201400:00:45|[1390]|[387]|17.64|10
140121060|01/01/201400:00:46|[1112]|[867]|26.46|10
140121062|01/01/201400:00:47|[182]|[13]|4,117.60|10
140121065|01/01/201400:00:48|[1088]|[385]|1,147.04|10
```

I want to remove "," from the amount column as Im not able to put some operations on this column. "," is not coming in all columns. And Im using bash.

Comment: Judging by your sample input you could just delete all commas everywhere with `tr -d , < file.txt > output`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{sub(",","",$(NF-1))}1' OFS='|' file
140121059|01/01/201400:00:45|[1390]|[387]|17.64|10
140121060|01/01/201400:00:46|[1112]|[867]|26.46|10
140121062|01/01/201400:00:47|[182]|[13]|4117.60|10
140121065|01/01/201400:00:48|[1088]|[385]|1147.04|10
```

`$(NF-1)` refers to the second to last field, we only replace comma in this field.

If you want to remove comma in all field, you can use `tr` instead:

```
$ <file tr -d ',' > out_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file contains comma only in the `amount` field, you can use the command as below.

```
 sed 's/,//g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use sed:

```
sed 's/,//g' filename
```